# Why spring application runned with docker ends unexpected with code 0?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I create my app according to the link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-postgresql-docker

When i run my app
I always have

```
    app    | 2021-04-02 01:08:34.014  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 2.279 seconds (JVM running for 2.946)
app    | 2021-04-02 01:08:34.019  INFO 1 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
app    | 2021-04-02 01:08:34.022  INFO 1 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
app    | 2021-04-02 01:08:34.027  INFO 1 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
app exited with code 0
```

**app exited with code 0**

When I try to do any GET in postman it runs an error

I did a simple RestController, just for tests

How can I avoid it?

Did I write something I shouldn't in the docker files?

Comment: put debug=true in your application.properties and try again

Comment: It seems db connection pool is not starting properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when i run it with :

```
docker-compose up --build
```

than is works perfectly.
Could someone explain this?